# Convergence of complex series and real constants

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Studying for a test I found this question:

> What are the conditions for the convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{a^n+b^n}$$ where $z\in\mathbb{C}, b\leq a <0,a$ and $b$ real numbers given.

So my first idea was to use the root test for the absolute series series, that is,$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|z^n|}{|a^n+b^n|}$$

But what can I do with $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|z|}{\sqrt[n]{|a^n+b^n|}}?$$

I know that I need this less than one for the convergence of series, but it is a suficient condition? And how can I formalize this?

Furthermore, what can I do for a conditional convergence? If $|z| = 1, z\neq1$, I know I can apply Dirichlet Test since $|a|>1,|b|>1$. But what can we say about other cases?

Thanks for attetion, any help would be aprreciated.

Comment: somebody has any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test#Application_to_power_series) applied to  convergence of a power series $\sum_na_nz^n$ states that if $1/R:=\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$, then the series converges (absolutely) inside the disk $B(0;R)=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|<R\}$, and diverges outside $B(0;R)$. It does not provide information of what happens at  boundary $|z|=R$.

Under the assumptions of the OP, $0<|a|\leq |b|$. Suffices to consider the case $|a|<|b|$.  Then $0<a/b<1$ and
$$\sqrt[n]{|a^n+b^n|}=|b|\sqrt[n]{|1+(a/b)^n|}=|b|\sqrt[n]{1+(a/b)^n}$$
Hence
$$|b|<\sqrt[n]{|a^n+b^n|}<|b|\sqrt[n]{2}$$
Letting $n\rightarrow\infty$ yields that $\lim_n\sqrt[n]{|a^n+b^n|}=|b|$. The ratio test implies that the series in the OP converges absolutely inside the disk $|z|<|b|$ and diverges for all $z$ with $|z|>|b|$.
On the boundary $|z|=|b|$ observe that
$$\frac{|b|^n}{|a^n+b^n|}=\frac{1}{1+(a/b)^n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}1\neq0$$
This the series diverges for all $|z|=|b|$.